# Ionic downloads from github - can I avoid doing this with each new app?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to `Ionic` and just getting used to it. However I have noticed that when I create an app files are download from `github` such as:

> Downloading:
>   https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip

Often working without internet access is there a way that files I might need can be downloaded once and stored locally?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can avoid downloading it with each new app. When you wrote something like to

> $ ionic start YourAppName tabs

`tabs` - is an alias to Ionic starter repository. You can replace with relative or absolute path to a local directory.

Check out more about start parameters there - [Starting an Ionic App](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start.html).

**EDIT:** I don't see a reason why the code below couldn't work. And Yes, you have to unpack your default app files to some folder.

> $ ionic start YourAppName c:\Temp\ionic-app-base-master

Comment: So if I download the ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip folder and store it locally how does ionic know where to look?

Answer (score 0):

The command `ionic start myApp` will always create your project with the latest version of Ionic. It will always download the github. Currently there is no how to create a new project without using the downlod of the github.

You can create a blank project and uses it as "boilerplate project" (`ionic start myApp blank`). Then, when necessary,  to update the Ionic (newest version) go to the root of your project and run `ionic lib update`.

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded all the templates into blank projects and will play around.

Answer (score 0):

Just download all the templates once and use it whenever you need when you are offline. Ionic will always download latest bundle when you do:

```
ionic start MyApp
```